# Cluster Index Scan 96%

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am seeing this Cluster Index Scan at 96% and I am not sure why that is? In the table I have a clustered index on the PK and a non-clustered on the where condition so should this being using the  non-clustered?

[image]

Comment: It means almost all of the cost is in that scan. In and of itself, that doesn't mean anything bad. If you drive 6 hours without stopping, you'll probably use 96% of your gas, and if you don't charge your phone for three days, you'll probably use 96% of your battery. With execution plans, operations will always add up to 100% of the cost (well, when SSMS is doing math right). Whether your index should be used, no idea, you didn't provide anywhere enough detail (table/index definition, query, statistics, execution plan). But if your index is used, something in that plan will also add up to 100%.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron mentioned you need to mention more details about table and index definition which will help us to help you in answering why the scan.

I am not covering the cost answer as it’s nicely stated in comments why you see that. However just looking at predicate there might be a possibility that all required columns does not suffice from existing NC index. Therefore depending upon how many rows are fetched optimizer would have decided to against key lookups as it would have been more costly than doing CI scan

Without looking at query and some of those existing index definitions hard to answer. If you can update your question with that, will try to edit my answer with more explanation